# AES Encryption - Encrypt Bytes

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I am trying to encrypt bytes with Aes. However, the output I get is really weird. Here is my functions (encrypt and decrypt). Am I doing something wrong?

```
public static byte[] encryptStream(byte[] plain, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        byte[] encrypted; ;
        using (MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(mstream,
                    aesProvider.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Write(plain, 0, plain.Length);
                }

            }
            encrypted = mstream.ToArray();
        }
        return encrypted;
    }

public static byte[] decryptStream(byte[] encrypted, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        byte[] plain;
        using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(mStream,
                    aesProvider.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Read(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);
                }
            }
            plain = mStream.ToArray();
        }
        return plain;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your `decryptStream()` method, when you read from the cryptoStream you read INTO the encrypted buffer. When you call `Read()` you are already reading from the encrypted buffer because you wrapped it with the memory stream. You want to read into a NEW buffer which concatenated together will be the decrypted bytes.

```
    public static byte[] decryptStream(byte[] encrypted, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        byte[] plain;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        int totalRead = 0;
        MemoryStream plainStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(encrypted))
        {
            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(mStream,
                    aesProvider.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int read = cryptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, encrypted.Length);

                        if (read == 0)
                            break;
                        else
                            plainStream.Write(buffer, totalRead, read);

                        totalRead += read;
                    }

                }
            }

            plain = plainStream.ToArray();
        }
        return plain;
    }
```